# HW: Unfolding a list in a specific way

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, unfold

In Programming in Haskell, Graham Hutton defines an unfold for lists as follows:

```
unfold :: (b -> Bool ) -> (b -> a) -> (b -> b) -> b -> [a]
unfold p h t x | p x = []
| otherwise = h x : unfold p h t (t x)
```

Define a function

```
• listUnfold :: (b -> Bool) -> (b -> a) -> (b -> b) -> b -> [a]
```

that is similar to the one above but uses unfoldr in its implementation and is non-recursive.

I've been trying for a while to solve the question above but I still can manage to do so (pretty new in Haskell and functional programming in general).

My attempt:

```
listUnfold :: (b -> Bool) -> (b -> a) -> (b -> b) -> b -> [a]
listUnfold f h t x 
    | f x == True   = []
    | otherwise     = h x : 
        listUnfoldr (\x -> if f x then Nothing else Just ((h x), (t x))) x
```

In english, if `f x` is true, return the empty list. Otherwise, use `h x` as the head and append the results of unfoldr as the tail. Unfoldr takes a list `(x:xs)` should recurse itself with `x` as the head and `xs` as the tail.

p/s: I'm probably doing this very very wrongly.

Comment: Hint: You're not using `t` at all.

Comment: @hammar Oops, copied the wrong code but this is still wrong for sure.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You've almost got it! The original function uses the function `p` (for 'predicate') to determine whether we've finished unfolding, `h` to apply to each element, and `t` (for 'transformation') to transform an element into the seed for the rest of the list.

`unfoldr` expects a single function `f :: b -> Maybe (a,b)`, which returns `Nothing` if we've finished unfolding, or `Just (x, y)`, where `x` is the element to add to the list and `y` is the seed for the rest of the list.

So `f` in `unfoldr` is responsible for the functionality of all three of `p`, `h` and `t`. The `Nothing`-or-`Just` dichotomy plays the part of the Boolean function `p`, and the second element of the tuple does `t`'s job of supplying the seed for the rest of the list.

Here's my solution (I've renamed the variables from your question, for clarity):

```
listUnfold pred f trans seed =
    unfoldr (\x -> if pred x
                   then Nothing
                   else Just (f x, trans x)) seed
```

Of course, when a value appears on the right-hand-end of a definition, as `seed` does here, you can take advantage of Haskell's sexy syntax for currying and throw it away altogether:

```
listUnfold pred f trans = unfoldr (\x -> if pred x
                                         then Nothing
                                         else Just (f x, trans x))
```

Formally, this transformation is known as [eta reduction](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Eta_conversion).

Comment: Wow, renaming the variables made everything so much more meaningful and easier to understand. Thanks!

Comment: I suspected that might have been what was confusing you ;)

Answer (score 2):

Here's the [definition of `unfoldr`](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/src/Data-List.html#unfoldr):

```
unfoldr                 :: (b -> Maybe (a, b)) -> b -> [a]
unfoldr f b  =
  case f b of
   Just (a,new_b) -> a : unfoldr f new_b
   Nothing        -> []
```

And here's Hutton's `unfold`, rewritten slightly to use `case` instead of guards:

```
unfold :: (b -> Bool ) -> (b -> a) -> (b -> b) -> b -> [a]
unfold p h t x =
  case p x of
    True  -> []
    False -> h x : unfold p h t (t x)
```

Some observations:

- By comparing types, we can see that `unfoldr` and `unfold` share the same final argument type and the same result type.

  - `b` in the definition of `unfoldr` and `x` in the definition of `unfold` are basically the same variable.
  - Hopefully we can also match up the definitions of the two functions so that the results are the same.
- Each function consists of a `case` expression, with two branches.
- In each function, one of those branches results in `[]`.

  - So when `p x = True`, we want `f x = Nothing`.
- In each function, the other branch results in `{-something-} : {-recursive-call-}`.

  - So when `p x = False`, we want `f x = Just ({-something-}, {-something-else-})`.

By now it should be clear that `unfold p h t x = unfoldr f x where f = ...`, and it's not too difficult to carry on the chain of reasoning and fill in the definition of `f`.